# long loading page and viewstate

Tags: jsf

## Some background knowledge

In certain circumstances, a page generated by JSF can take some times to be fully loaded. Let it be the network is poor (i.e mobile network), the server is cheap, the page is way bigger (which is more and more the case with today highly javascript focused component), the end user device being outdated and not handling all these javascript as fast as we'd like, or any other reasons.

Moreover, with all the jsf library asking (forcing?) you to use post methods to use fancy features, the user input must always have a valid jsf viewstate ready to be used, to be answered correctly.

In these cases, for the end user, it shouldn't be a pain to quickly navigate to other page of the applications or use already loaded feature without having him to load the whole page before doing so.

By default, on mojarra and myfaces implementations, the viewstate is generated at the end of the render view phase to be able to catch any state change that could happen in the render view phase.

Mojarra has a context parameter ([com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/09/what-mojarra-context-parameters-are.html)) to change this behavior but this doesn't handle the fact that the state could change during the render view phase and there is no similar option on myfaces.

## Approach

***My first question is what would be the best approach to handle this scenario ?***

As a starting point, I would assume that only server side state saving is used to limit the bandwidth used. This ought to cover most of the previous examples (except "server being cheap")

Then, improve the mojarra way of doing it by generating the view state id to be send to the client as soon as possible, and save the real state after the form is completely encoded so the last state change are saved.

The caveat here would be in case of slow or busy server, a subsequent request with that view state id could be received before the state is even fully written. And this case should have to wait before starting its own process.

## Implementation

***My second question, assuming the aforementioned approach is valid, would be how would you achieve this in a manner that's totally portable ?***

I didn't really think about it but it looks like meddling with the view state writting of the different implementations could be tricky and could lead to serious brain overload to know which implementation do what. So maybe there is a way of doing so only by using jsf spec mechanism.

Comment: As you answered your first question saving states at the server side will help you on poor networks. Also using gzip is very helpful on jsp and jsf frameworks.

Comment: And using 'ajax' helps

Comment: And checking server side performance issues in your own code

Comment: These are all valid concern, but i'd like to also tackle the viewstate issue. To be clear, some benchmark'ing has been done on our part and we cannot optimize the server part anymore, (which we reduced to approximately deliver a page in under 50ms). This is a heavy application with lots of functionality on each page that "can't" be reduced. The aforementioned factors are not really on our end as customer will install it on their infra (we suggest some prerequisite)

Comment: *"The caveat here would be in case of slow or busy server, a subsequent request with that view state id could be received before the state is even fully written."* Have you reproduced this? How exactly? Because the average webbrowser/webserver uses the same HTTP connection for this and thus it simply goes into the queue. At least, I've never seen the here theoretized problem to actually have happened in real world.

Comment: @BalusC You are probably right, in most case the keep-alive feature of HTTP/TCP is used. I didn't reproduce this but theoretically it "could" happen as a 'worst-case-scenario' so I didn't want to omit it. It probably can be ignored to avoid some hard work though.